# Allow rotation in shouldAutoRotate - But stop all views from rotating - iOS

Tags: ios, orientation, autorotate

Edit: (Camera roll == image gallery)

Right now I have an app with 2 view controllers, where 2nd is presented modally from 1st. What I want to do is to create something similar to what iOS default camera app does, swipe finger left to right and pan to bring in camera roll.

I am planning to create a scroll view and add both views side by side.

Currently there is no rotation support in 1st view controller, which is the camera. But in the 2nd screen, auto rotation is enabled for all orientations.

If I put both to a single scroll view, how should I go about implementing the shouldAutorotate methods in the 2 view controllers? View controllers are different, but both will be present at the same time in the memory)

I don't want to autorotate anything in camera screen, but I want autorotation when the camera roll is pulled in. Also while the scroll view visible content is camaera screen, and device is rotated, the camera roll part should rotate, so that panning finger from left to right brings in the camera roll in correct orientation.

I see an option, allow autorotation in both VC's, but set the camera screen views' positions according to the new origin such that it seems like nothing has been rotated.

Other option is to not allow autorotate while scroll view displays camera screen, and start allowing it when camera roll comes in. But then if I am in camera screen, I have to play with positions of scroll view and camera roll so that pan works correctly.

1st option seems to be better... but still not cool enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you're presenting some viewcontroller modally it gets higher in controllers hierarchy and this viewcontroller is the only controller getting rotation notifications at that time. other controllers are "deaf".
You can get rotation notifications also in your app delegate.
Since camera roll should be presented modally too, you need to tackle with your two view controllers.

If I were you, I would just handle the case when the user scroll in the end of his image gallery, the next swipe gesture would present you camera roll ( you dont need your camera roll while you're browsing photos )

Comment: in image gallery, there is a scroll view for the images. But I'll put another scroll view for camera screen and the gallery. so that when I swipe left when I am on the last image in gallery, scroll view comes into play and camera screen comes in.